# I installed node.js and could not run "npm start" to work on react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

im trying to setup react js for the first time, but after setting up node,npm and react app i run "npm start" command and i get an error.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

i have tried to install by following the steps from above link.
but i have got the below errors.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT   
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Emitted 'error' event at:

 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! sample@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the sample@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-21T18_20_23_976Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you run npm install first?

Comment: Yep, **npm install** (in the project root directory) seems to be missing. **cd** to your project’s root directory, and run **npm install**. This command downloads and installs the project dependencies.

Comment: Have you used npm before or is this the first time for all of it?

Comment: Did you following `Installing ReactJS using webpack and babel` or `Using the create-react-app command`? Using the second approach avoids a lot of setup and should work immediately.

Comment: You should be able to run `npm start` right after you `npx create-react-app my-app` and 'cd my-app'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `create-react-app` available on this [link](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started). It's easier and you can avoid a lot of trouble later having to create *build* scripts and other stuff.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```